# Why won't Excel autofit my row height? [Microsoft Excel 2013]

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

[Microsoft Excel 2013]

This row looks like it should auto fit to the height of just 1 line, but autofit is not working here. I've checked and there are no merged cells, and I've even disabled wrap text on all the columns just in case it's causing some weird behavior. Does anyone have any ideas?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you manually set the height? Does it look right or does some text now flow?  What happens if you copy the section that is not autofitting correctly to a new book and select paste special, values.  Does the new book autofit correctly? If it does, then on a new sheet just choose paste, does it also autofit correctly?

Comment: Solution for me was a hidden column with more content than unhidden columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the =trim formula in case you have a lot of empty spaces.  Or as bvaughn stated, try manually setting the row height via format in the Home ribbon.  That same selection will let you pick auto format row height.

Looks like you are creating a table, so potentially you could just select all of the data and insert table with headers.

Or you could select the row that isn't auto adjusting the height and hit the down arrow on clear and clear formats.